# FBX Import Errors: "Multiple roots are found in the bone hierarchy"

Tags: unreal-4, blender, skeletal-animation

[image]I followed these steps:

1. I exported my character from Blender as an fbx file
2. I went to Unreal Engine and make a new folder
3. I paste the fbx file in that folder
4. I put and tried to put it with a skeleton

I get the following errors:

> ❕ No smoothing group information was found in this FBX scene.
>
> ❕ Could not find the bind pose. It will use time 0 as bind pose.
>
> Multiple roots are found in the bone hierarchy. We only support single root bone.
>
> ❕ Get Import Data has failed.

I think it is an issue with Blender. Specifically, I think it is a problem with the spine names. The character has a skeleton I on it in Blender.

[[image: Screenshot of error messages1]

Comment: The errors seem to complain that there is more than one root bone (more than one bone in the file that has no parent bone). Can you show us the contents of your Blender file so we can help you find this stray orphan bone and re-parent it or exclude it from the export?

Comment: @DMGregory hi i posted an update were you looking to see the bones section? i dont understand what you wanted me to show exactly i would be happy to plz hit me up

Comment: The only one I can help with is that the smoothing one is under the general section of the export tab.  By default, it's set to "Normals Only" which needs changing.  For the stuff I do, I change it to Faces but you may need something different.

Comment: @stephen ok I will try that